# HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse only works from Console app not ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

When I run the code below from a console app it works perfectly.

```
        Uri prereqUri = new Uri(PREREQ_URL);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(prereqUri);

        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, authorization);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        string responseString = "";
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
```

However when I run the same code from ASP.NET I get:

"System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
on var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()

Any ideas, please.

**Update:** The remote end is not seeing the data we send through ASP.NET so the problem is definitely on the sending side.
**Update 2 :** Some sites, suggest impersonation, that didn't work :(

Comment: Error is on this line: var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix the error? If so, what have you tried? Posting code and saying "This doesn't work" doesn't get very far :)

Comment: Please suggest what is there to try? I had an error in ASP.NET, I created a console app, copied the same code, and the code started working... I am stumped

Comment: Fiddler says: fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to stg.mul-bill.jp (for #27) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
If that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having not found a better solution and having code release deadline I am just going to call a Console app from the ASP.NET code. Solution is below

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Debug\ConsoleApp.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,

        Arguments = PREREQ_URL + " " + basicUserName
    };
    if (basicPassword.Length > 0) startInfo.Arguments += " " + basicPassword;

    string responseString = Process.Start(startInfo).StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    return responseString;
```

I realize that this is not an ideal solution and will delete/modify this answer if someone suggests a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I use HttpWebRequest in an ASP.NET application and works just fine.

Based on the error you see in Fiddler I would say it is a problem with the HTTPS certificate validation or the default security protocol. Probably a different default policy applies when you run the code in a console application and that is why it works there.
Try to add these lines below the *WebRequest.Create(..)*

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    // Skip validation of remote server's SSL/TLS certificate
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and resolved with setting proxy of httpwebrequest as below.

```
httpRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(hostname, portno);
```